# Gradle plugin, how to hook Jacoco agent to jvm

Tags: gradle, jacoco, dynamic-properties

Hello there Gradle gurus!
I'm seeking for your mighty experience and knowledge :)

I have a Gradle plugin that hooks a Jacoco agent to the jvm. Currently my code looks like this:

```
Task t = project.allTasks.getByPath(project.getName+":"+"test");
t.jvmArgs = ["-javaagent:"+jacocoAgentJar+"=destfile=" + coverageResultFile.getCanonicalPath()];
```

This is working fine but since dynamic properties are deprecated I want to somehow get rid of them. However... changing the code to `t.ext.jvmArgs = ["-javaagent:"+jacocoAgentJar+"=destfile=" + coverageResultFile.getCanonicalPath()];` doesnt work.

Could someone please explain to me how am I supposed to hook the Jacoco agent to the jvm withought using this dynamic property?

Thanks

Comment: try using `tasks.withType(Test) { .. }` so that its not a dynamic property on the generic task type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a "dynamic properties" warning here, there is likely something wrong with your code, and it's not just a style issue. For one thing, the use of `getAllTasks` (which, by the way, takes a boolean parameter) is inappropriate here. Instead, you should use `project.tasks.getByName("test")`, which can be abbreviated to `project.tasks["test"]` or even `project.test`. Or, if you want to catch all test tasks, `project.tasks.withType(Test)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can configure directly the test task in the build file adding a configuration closure  like this:

```
test{

  jvmArgs "javaagent:"+jacocoAgentJar+"=destfile=" + overageResultFile.getCanonicalPath()"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you may want to look into the [gradle-jacoco](HTTP://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-jacoco) plugin.